# Giving multiple hyperlinks in MS-Word VBA based on own delimiter

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA scripting. I am converting TeX file to Word document using GrindEq convertor. In this TeX file there have multiple `\href`commands. Here content only coming in MS-Word file (i.e`. https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6423(87)90036-0`). So far i am putting tag before and after for that content `<LaTeX-href-http>https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6423(87)90036-0</LaTeX-href-http>` using python. By this content was producing with Tag in MS-Word file.

Similarly for converting to Small Caps font, converting to Monospace font, i have recorded the macro and modify as per my own needs and used.

```
Sub XXX_SmallCaps()
'
' XXX_SmallCaps Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
        .SmallCaps = True
        .AllCaps = False
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\<LaTeX-SmallCaps\>(*@)\</LaTeX-SmallCaps\>"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
                
     
        
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    '
' XXX_Serif Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Size = 13
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\<LaTeX-SerifFont\>(*@)\</LaTeX-SerifFont\>"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
'
' XXX_MonoSpace
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\<LaTeX-MonospaceFont\>(*@)\</LaTeX-MonospaceFont\>"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
End Sub
```

But how to give the Hyperlinks for the content in between the Tags `<LaTeX-href-http>...</LaTeX-href-http>` and `<LaTeX-href-http>` and `</LaTeX-href-http>` tags need to deleted using in VBA? Please refer the image for my DOC file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example (including cleaning up your other code):

```
Sub ReformatLaTeX()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrLnk As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Replacement.Font.SmallCaps = True
    .Text = "\<LaTeX-SmallCaps\>(*@)\</LaTeX-SmallCaps\>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 13
    .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Text = "\<LaTeX-SerifFont\>(*@)\</LaTeX-SerifFont\>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 12
    .Replacement.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Text = "\<LaTeX-MonospaceFont\>(*@)\</LaTeX-MonospaceFont\>"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\<LaTeX-href-http\>*@\<\/LaTeX-href-http\>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    StrLnk = Split(Split(.Text, "</LaTeX-href-http>")(0), "<LaTeX-href-http>")(1)
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:=StrLnk, TextToDisplay:=StrLnk
    .Start = .Hyperlinks(1).Range.End
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But mainly `Split` function was not working for me and `.Hyperlinks` was not added between specified tag `<LaTeX-href-http>` and `</LaTeX-href-http>`

Comment: I have re-worked lucky i got what i need. I was changed the line `.Text = "<LaTeX-href-http>*@</LaTeX-href-http>"` to `.Text = "\<LaTeX-href-http\>(*@)\<\/LaTeX-href-http\>"`. Now it was working fine.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. This script was not working in my footnote text.

Comment: The code was only written to process content in the document body. You would need to modify the code to loop through all required StoryRanges. See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945362/detect-words-in-word-vba-that-contain-in-them/65948352#65948352

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I definitely try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `StoryRanges` was working fine even in my footnote also.